# Shir shel yom — "said" vs "sang"

Tags: prayer-book, shir-shel-yom

Why by the shir shel yom  does it say "The leviem **said**" instead of saying "The Leviem **sang**?"

Comment: The word "omrim" can mean "recited". Just poiting this out. Oftentimes Hebrew words can have multiple English translations.

Comment: How do you know they sang it?

Comment: @DoubleAA Songs are sung, no? Seems like a logical assumption to me.

Comment: @ezra and how do you know it's a song? Maybe it's a poem which was dramatically read? Levite poetry slam?

Comment: @DoubleAA Based on the fact that we call it the **Shir** Shel Yom.

Comment: I see no proof there one way or another. A wise man once said "Oftentimes Hebrew words can have multiple English translations"

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Dovid Cohen (in his Sefer משאת כפי pg 104)suggests, that it is to indicate that the main part of shira was the part that was done orally, and not the musical instruments.

Comment: If you're referring to the Gemara in Sukkah and Arakhin about Ikkar Shirah beFeh you should really add some clarification since most people won't understand what you're saying